# What is half width of gain profile? why is it used as delta lamda while calculating number of longitudinal modes? (Correct me if wrong on this)

Tags: laser, normal-modes, laser-cavity

How many longitudinal modes can be excited for an He-Ne laser in a cavity of length 30 cm and having half width of gain profile of laser material 2 ×〖10〗^(-3) nm? The emission wavelength is 6328 Å.

Comment: Welcome to Phsysics Stack Exchange! What have you tried so far? Where exactly did you get stuck?

Comment: Thank you for replying :)

Using these two relations, | df/f | = | dw/w | and Spacing between adjacent modes = c/2L 

Where f is frequency, w is the wavelength and L is the length of the active medium.

Number of Axial modes(N) = delta f/ Spacing, 

rearranging this we get N = (dw)(2L)/(w*w)

Not sure what to substitute in place of dw and why?